# Showing progress bar on the pag while doing computation on the server

Tags: python, web-applications

I was trying to use webapp to create a page that computes something and gives back to user the answer.

Basically I have something like:

```
class Index(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        computeforlongtime()
        return pagewithanswer
```

Where pagewithanswer is the html page string. So as for now it requires user to wait long time and than shows the answer. How can I change it so that it shows some kind of a progress bar or whatever? The page gets displaced when I return from the method and I don't see a way to ommit this.

I'd really appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to use ajax calls ... you would do this in your html page with javascript ... where you say something like `$('#some_div').load("/a/rout/to/class/Index")`  where somediv has some animated progressbar in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's plenty of way to do this, depends on what you really want, I'll try to drop some:

1. Do the query using XMLHttpRequest (Better use a framework like jQuery), show an indeterminate progress bar during operation, display the result in place of the progress bar when you get it.

   - Pros: Super easy
   - Cons: The user don't know the progression, nor if its still really running
2. Do the query using XMLHttpRequest, let the server store its progress somewhere, query from time to time using XMLHttpRequest the current state of the progression, display a determinate progress bar, you may find a library that can compute an estimation of remaining time

   - Pros:

     - The user have a feedback about real progression
     - You can display the progress bar on different devices at the same time, even create a view of "all running jobs".
   - Cons:

     - polling progression every second may cost you some CPU server side with a lot of users
3. Do the query using XMLHttpRequest, do the server send back the progression from time to time to the client. You can use every push technology to do this from old' school HTTP long polling to web sockets. You may use tools like RabbitMQ, crossbar.io, or whatever.

   - Pro: You may reuse your newly installed crossbar.io for so many other things
   - Con: Wow, installing crossbar.io to push a progression... !
4. You may stream the progress in the HTTP response by flushing buffers from time to time, like the twitter stream API

   - Pro: Seems very easy
   - Con: You may be beaten by so many little tricky thinks like caches, buffers, ...